# Accessing environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, dynamic-method

I am setting the below environment variable.

```
ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"] = "/prefix"
```

Is there any way of accessing this env variable other than `ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"]`?
I know rails env can be accesses like `Rails.env`. Can all the env variables be accesses like that or is it something special for rails_env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rails.env` only gives you the value of `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` or `ENV["RACK_ENV"]`. If none of them were set, it returns `"development"`.

The `ENV` object is provided by Ruby.

For another way to access it, you might consider either implementing it by yourself, or using the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem. Set environment variables in a YAML config. Then they can be accessed like this:

```rb
Figaro.env.rails_relative_url_root
```